# OpenCV HoughLines only ever returning one line

Tags: java, opencv

I've shifted my OpenCV development from Python to Java, to work with it on an Android device. The first step was to port a fairly straightforward Canny/HoughLines algorithm. With some research, I wound up with:

```
    Mat lines = inputFrame.gray();

    Mat cny=new Mat();

    Imgproc.Canny(lines,cny,100,150);

    Mat lns = new Mat();

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(cny, lns, 1, Math.PI/180, 50, 20, 20);
    Log.w("MainActivity",String.valueOf(lns.cols()));


    return cny;
```

The problem with this code is that it always prints '1' or '0' lines. From the same angle as my Python code, which returned 100s of lines with the same threshold and other values, this code returns one.

I've tried tuning all of the parameters, with no luck. The returned Mat from Canny shows reasonable edges, but HoughLines (both standard, and probabilistic) will always return only one line.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you add images? original image, canny, detected line

Comment: can you print nr of rows too? and in c++ the return type typically id a vector (array) of vec4b elements instead of a mat (which might be possible too though)

Comment: I am having the same issue, any luck?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The rows and columns are different in the Java wrapper. Instead of .cols use .rows and when you want to get the data instead of lines.get(0, i) use lines.get(i, 0)

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why this isn't documented anywhere?

Comment: You save my day. Thanks